# Kubuntu LiveCD shuts down computer

Tags: kubuntu, shutdown, live-cd

A bit of background before the problem. I have two computers, one was running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and working as a server, the other running Win7 64-bit. While trying to test new hardware for the server (which has been non-operational for a month or more), Windows did a Windows thing, and now won't boot back up. I opted to fix that issue later, and tried testing the new hardware from a Kubuntu LiveCD I have on a 16GB flash drive. Boots up and runs, but after about 10 minutes, the screen goes blank, with the number 92 in the bottom right corner of the screen, and then about a minute later the machine reboots, and then stays in a reboot cycle until I hit the reset button on the case.

Thinking that I may have bad hardware, I put the flash drive on my Windows machine. It also runs, and appears to be more stable, but instead of just testing each time, I've tried to go ahead and attempt an install to a 40GB drive I have that doesn't have any data that I cannot afford to lose. During the install process, the computer will just shut down without warning. Just suddenly off. I can go press the power button and it will boot right back up, but when the install gets to about 45% of copying files, the system simply shuts down.

I don't think this is a heat issue, as the case is wide open with excellent airflow at the moment, and all of the components were dusted with compressed air before I started this. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something to make this whole thing work, but I'm not sure what just yet.

Comment: Perhaps there was an error when the flash drive was created. Plug the flash drive into a working GNU/Linux system (like your Ubuntu server while it's still on 12.04) and open a terminal. cd to the mount point for your flash drive and then run the following command: "md5sum -c md5sum*". If there are any errors, they will be at the bottom of the output and you will need to put Kubuntu on the flash drive again.